# Export NetCDF Dimension Name

Tags: export

In the NetCDF format, I can define a common dimension with a specified name. Then when I create variables, I can have the dimensions of those variables reference the same dimension name. Is there away todo this when exporting from Mathematica? I have some data I'm trying to export

```
Export["test.nc",
 {"Datasets" -> {
    "x" -> fullData[[;; , 1]],
    "y" -> fullData[[;; , 2]],
    "z" -> fullData[[;; , 3]],
    "x_norm" -> fullData[[;; , 4]],
    "y_norm" -> fullData[[;; , 5]],
    "z_norm" -> fullData[[;; , 6]]
    },
  "DataFormat" -> {
    "Real64",
    "Real64",
    "Real64",
    "Real64",
    "Real64",
    "Real64"
    }}, "Rules"]
```

But I need it to show up in the NetCDF file as

```
dimension:
  size = 963;
variables:
  double x(size=963);
  double y(size=963);
  double z(size=963);
  double x_norm(size=963);
  double y_norm(size=963);
  double z_norm(size=963);
```

Instead of

```
dimension:
  xDim = 963;
  yDim = 963;
  zDim = 963;
  x_normDim = 963;
  y_normDim = 963;
  z_normDim = 963;
variables:
  double x(xDim=963);
  double y(yDim=963);
  double z(zDim=963);
  double x_norm(x_normDim=963);
  double y_norm(y_normDim=963);
  double z_norm(z_normDim=963);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WL 13.1+ this is not only possible but rather straightforward:

```
In[1]:= fullData = RandomReal[1., {963, 6}];

In[2]:= Export["test.nc", {
  "Dimensions" -> {"size" -> 963},
  "Datasets" -> {
    "x" -> {"Data" -> fullData[[All, 1]], "DimensionNames" -> "size"},
    "y" -> {"Data" -> fullData[[All, 2]], "DimensionNames" -> "size"},
    "z" -> {"Data" -> fullData[[All, 3]], "DimensionNames" -> "size"},
    "x_norm" -> {"Data" -> fullData[[All, 4]], "DimensionNames" -> "size"},
    "y_norm" -> {"Data" -> fullData[[All, 5]], "DimensionNames" -> "size"},
    "z_norm" -> {"Data" -> fullData[[All, 6]], "DimensionNames" -> "size"}
    }}, "Rules"]

Out[2]= "test.nc"
```

Check that datasets have correct dimensions by importing the file back:

```
In[3]:= Import["test.nc", "Dimensions"]

Out[3]= <|"/x" -> {963}, "/x_norm" -> {963}, "/y" -> {963}, 
 "/y_norm" -> {963}, "/z" -> {963}, "/z_norm" -> {963}|>

In[4]:= Import["test.nc", "DimensionNames"]

Out[4]= <|"/x" -> {"size"}, "/x_norm" -> {"size"}, "/y" -> {"size"}, 
 "/y_norm" -> {"size"}, "/z" -> {"size"}, "/z_norm" -> {"size"}|>
```

And just to be sure, confirm with `ncdump`:

```
➜  ~ ncdump -h test.nc
netcdf test {
dimensions:
    size = 963 ;
variables:
    double x(size) ;
    double y(size) ;
    double z(size) ;
    double x_norm(size) ;
    double y_norm(size) ;
    double z_norm(size) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the problem remains unsolved after versions and FYI, here's a temporary solution:

1. Export your data array to some *Python*-readable format file. `HDF5` may do well. ([163685](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163687/69875))
2. Import the data array from file to *Python*.
3. Use [`netCDF4` library](https://annefou.github.io/metos_python/02-formats/) to export the desired *NetCDF*.